# How to write apexpages.currentPage.getParameter('token') in Aura components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to fetch the token parameter from lightning component app URL. In visualforce page, inside the Apex class controller we can fetch using apexpages.currentpage............
But in Aura components how to fetch the parameter from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams#example) for this:

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.token", new URL(window.location).searchParams.get('token'));
    }
})
```